# Can you use django extra(select={}) to select multiple fields?

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to add two new fields to my django product queryset and I do something like this

```
products = Product.objects.filter(company=company).filter(Q(name__icontains=search_term) | Q(code__icontains=search_term))
products = products.extra(select={"is_distributed": product_is_distributed_query(False)})
products = products.extra(select={"expense_type": product_expense_type_query(False)})
```

But the two queries (product_is_distributed_query and product_expense_type_query) are identical just returning different fields. Can I do this in only one extra(select{}) by using just one query to return both fields?

The query would be like this:

```
def product_is_distributed_query(use_product_code):
product_query = """
select vt.is_distributed, coalesce(et.name, '')
from (
    SELECT
        cp.id, 
    CASE WHEN SUM(coalesce(snp.id, 0)) > 0 THEN true
        ELSE false
    END as is_distributed,
    max(coalesce(snp.expense_type_id, 0)) as maxId1

    FROM
        core_product AS cp
    LEFT JOIN
        stock_non_product AS snp
    ON (cp.name = snp.name """
product_query = product_query + ("AND cp.code = snp.code" if use_product_code else "")
product_query += """    
        AND cp.company_id = snp.company_id AND snp.is_deleted = false)
    LEFT JOIN expense_type as et ON(snp.expense_type_id = et.id AND snp.company_id = et.company_id)
    WHERE
        cp.id = core_product.id
        AND cp.company_id = core_product.company_id
    --         AND snp.company_id = core_product.company_id
    GROUP BY
        cp.id
) as vt
-- LEFT JOIN stock_non_product AS snp ON(snp.id = maxId)
LEFT JOIN expense_type as et ON(et.id = vt.maxId)
"""

return product_query
```

instead of being two separated queries that are identical to this one but return one or the other field